# mysql: Join product table with latest product prices

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table productPrice which contains more than one price for several  products:

```
productPrice: 
id, 
unixTime, 
productId, 
price
```

I query the latest product prices and an average of all prices for this product in the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT AVG(price) FROM productPrice WHERE productId =19 AND unixTime >= (unix_timestamp(NOW())-86400)) as avg, 
price,
unixTime  
FROM productPrice 
WHERE productId =19
ORDER BY unixTime DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This returns the latest price, unixTime and the average price in a reasonable time (in my opinion - there may be a better way to do this).
I have another table products, this is where I get the productId from:

```
products:
id (=productId in productPrice),
name,
url
```

I would like to select * from products and use the productId to join the result with the latest price and the average price, to get a result for all products like:

```
id,name,url,unixTime,price,avg
```

I read many similar questions here, but none seemed to work for me.
Is there a good way to do this, or should I select the product first and do a single select for each productId after?
Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: Included unixTime in the result to get more than one column from productPrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with correlated subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select avg(price) 
        from productPrice pp
        where pp.productId = p.productid and
              unixTime > (unix_timestamp(NOW()) - 86400)
      ) as avgprice,
       (select price
        from productPrice pp
        where pp.productId = p.productid 
        order by unixTime desc
        limit 1
      ) as mostrecentprice
from products p;
```

For performance, you want an index on `productPrice(productid, unixtime, price)`.

Comment: This works great, thank you very much! I can only include a single column in the second select and could not add unixTime for example, right? This was not part of the original question, but what could I do about this?

Comment: @user1840267 . . . You would need an additional correlated subquery to get another column value.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test here, but I believe that this might work:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.url, pp.price, (SELECT AVG(pr.price) FROM productPrice pr WHERE pr.productId = p.id AND pr.unixTime >= (unix_timestamp(NOW()) - 86400)) avg,
FROM productPrice pp INNER JOIN products p ON pp.productId = p.id
WHERE pp.productId = 19
ORDER BY pp.unixTime DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, Allan - but how do I get pp.productId? I think I still need to select all ids first and then do a single select for each id...?

Comment: I believe that removing the where clause would get you all the rows